# Is PHP include for remote files via CDN performant?

Tags: php, cdn

I've developed a PHP Application Development Platform that I want to use for all the projects I'm going to be working on.

However, rather than installing the framework on all the multiple projects, I want to house it in a CDN (a la Rackspace Cloud Files) and then include the parts I need when I need it.

```
include("<path_to_cdn>/myfile.php");
```

I see this a lot with Javascript (e.g. JQuery), however I'm unsure if it's the right approach for PHP.

Kindly advise.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your reasons for wanting to do this? It seems quite unlikely to be a good idea...

Comment: This sounds awfully brittle. Why not just setup processes to copy the files from a CDN every so often (maybe once a day/week)?

Comment: @Matt: Ok. It was just a thought though. Lesson learned.

Comment: @Jared: Thanks for the tip. I had considered trying to setup something that would involve GitHub i.e. synchronize my local files with my GitHub Repo for the PHP framework. I guess this makes better sense?

Comment: I could see some problems with any kind of cross-site synchronization script, since you technically won't be testing the distributed code before it gets pushed out to each site. I would really do some research on multi-site management; for instance, ExpressionEngine has a [plugin](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/multiple_site_manager/) that simplifies multi-site management across sites. You would do better just having a single codebase if possible; if not, I would seriously think hard about how you will test changes before you change a source file.

Comment: @Chuck Wasn't meant as a criticism -- it was just difficult to answer your question without knowing exactly why you were wanting to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the performance of remote `include()` is very poor. (Consider that PHP must fetch and reparse the content on every request — PHP opcode caches only work for local includes.) Also keep in mind that newer versions of PHP disable `allow_url_include` by default for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking at multiple scenarios. Perhaps GitHub repo synchronization would be the way to go. Will have to try and figure out something.